# Using Connectify with Proxy

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I connect to the internet via a http tunneler which uses a proxy, Is there any way I can channel all incoming connectify connections through that particular IP and port address? . .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your proxy for going to internet which is proxy.PAC file hosted on http://..  in your case then proxy server ip and http port is present in .pac file and if its hosted on url  then you can't edit it but you might view that file and get further details.

Location of that url exists in lan connections>proxy settings